# Laravel locatization not translating

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-localization

Okay so in my app.blade.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        //....
    </head>
    <body class="bg-black text-white flex flex-col min-h-screen page-{{ Route::currentRouteName() }}">
        {{-- Navbar --}}
        @include('layouts.navbar')
 
        {{-- Page content --}}
        <div class="flex-1">
            @yield('content')
        </div>

        {{-- Footer --}}
        @include('layouts.footer')
    </body>
</html>
```

Now i want to use localization in the navbar so i did this (Lets call this block 1)

```
<div class="swiper-slide bg-primary"><div class="swiper-content mx-auto w-fit py-3 flex items-center gap-2"><i class="fas fa-concierge-bell"></i> {{ __('content/navbar.orange header 1') }}</div></div>
```

And thats working but now in the same file only 20 lines below the code above (Lets call this block 2)

```
<a href={{ route("home") }}><div class="text-lg xl:text-2xl font-bold @if(Request::is('/')) border-b-2 border-primary md:border-b-[4px] @endif">{{ __('content/navbar.nav link 1') }}</div></a>
```

I have this line of code but its always translated in english. But the weird part is that when my locale is set to FR the content of block 1 shows in FR but the content of block 2 shows in EN eventhough they are in the same file

Im super confused and cant figure out why that is

Any help is welcome!

If u need more code let me know!

Content and structure of Lang file

```
Lang/en/content/navbar.php
```

Content of EN file

```
<?php

// lang/en/content/navbar.php

return [
    'orange header 1' => 'Service to sold machines',
    'orange header 2' => 'Large stock',
    'orange header 3' => 'Transport to location',
    'orange header 4' => 'Trade-in possible',
    'nav link 1' => 'Home',
    'nav link 2' => 'Stock',
    'nav link 3' => 'Lease',
    'nav link 4' => 'Contact',
];
```

Content of FR file (Lang/fr/content/navbar.php)

```
<?php

// lang/fr/content/navbar.php

return [
    'orange header 1' => 'Service aux machines vendues',
    'orange header 2' => 'Stock important',
    'orange header 3' => "Transport à l'emplacement",
    'orange header 4' => "Reprise possible",
    'nav link 1' => 'Home',
    'nav link 2' => 'Stock',
    'nav link 3' => 'Louer',
    'nav link 4' => 'Contact',
];
```

First image shows the page in fr and second image in en but the navbar content is still the same eventhough the uspbars content is translated

[image: App locale set to FR]

[image: App locale set to EN]

Comment: can you post the content of the translation file ?

Comment: @ths added the content of translations file as edit

Comment: it is working, but because you have the same values in both translation files you think it doesn't. Try changing `'nav link 1' => 'Home'` in the FR file to `'nav link 1' => 'Accueil'` (for example) and check again.

Comment: @ths oh my bad i showt the wrong one, i actually have all 4 nav links in the file and they will not translate to fr, i know that because nav link 3 content is different in fr

Comment: so ? Did you try as I suggested ?

Comment: @ths Yes, i changed "Home" to "Test" and it still shows the english "Home" instead of "test", i also added a picture to be more clear

Comment: Caching your views? Also the way you're naming your translation keys is odd, they should  explain the string they're actually translating so it's clear.

Comment: try to debug the output of `__` function and see what does it return.

Comment: How to debug the output of __ ??

Comment: @ths, fixed it, made a stupid mistake :X

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh i had a piece of code between the uspsbar and navbar

```
            <li onclick="{{ App::setLocale("en") }}" class="flex items-center gap-2 text-white text-lg font-bold">
                      <a class="flex items-center gap-2" href="{{ route('locale.setting', 'en') }}">
                        <img class="h-5 w-7" src="{{ asset('img/flags/EN-flag.png') }}" alt="EN-flag"> EN
                      </a>
                    </li>
```

But the onclick sets the locale to en and forgot to remove the onclick function, my bad!

Thanks everyone!!!